# Restrict complexType with attributes in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm working with an XSD such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="algo">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="nota" type="t_algo" minOccurs="0"
                    maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="t_algo">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="[1][0]|[0-9]" />
    </xs:restriction>
    <xs:attribute name="modul" type="t_modul"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="t_modul">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="[m][0][0-9]"/>
    </xs:restriction> 
  </xs:simpleType> 

</xs:schema>
```

and using a test XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<algo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///D:/DAM/RECUF1/Mispruebas/telf.xsd">
  <nota modul="m01">0</nota>
  <nota modul="m01">7</nota>
  <nota modul="m01">3</nota>
  <nota modul="m01">1</nota>
</algo>
```

I want to have children `nota` with values between 0-10 and with the attribute `modul` with a value `m0X` where `x` between (0-9).  I thought the previous XSD would work, but it does not. Can somebody explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The pattern you specified for the `t_modul` simple type applies to the value contained inside the tags rather than the name of the attribute.  I believe the name of the attribute is fixed and you may have to define tags for the various types of attribute names which you are expecting.

Comment: Don't tell us that something doesn't work. Tell us how it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to have an attribute on an element with restricted content, define a new `xs:simpleType` and then use `xs:extension` to extend it with an attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:element name="algo">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="nota" type="t_algo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="t_algo">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="t_algo_content">
        <xs:attribute name="modul" type="t_modul"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="t_modul">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="m0[0-9]"/>
    </xs:restriction> 
  </xs:simpleType> 

  <xs:simpleType name="t_algo_content">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
      <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
      <xs:maxInclusive value="10"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

Note also that I've simplified your regex pattern in the first case and used `minInclusive`/`maxInclusive` to more naturally express your integer range in the second case.